# What do the bracketed numbers on the Salmon Run results mean?

Tags: splatoon-3

On the end results screen for Splatoon 3's Salmon Run, there is a small number in brackets next to the number of Golden Eggs collected. What does this small bracketed number mean?

[image: salmon run player results]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Splatoon3/comments/xf3okx/salmon_run_question/):

> It’s the number of eggs you threw that someone else put in the basket. Basically the Salmon Run equivalent of an assist stat.

Comment: Does this count eggs dropped in a [Big Shot launcher](https://splatoonwiki.org/wiki/Big_Shot)?

Comment: In my opinion, yes. But I should verify this.